# Sum of distance between every pair of same element in an array

Tags: arrays, math

I have an array [a0,a1,...., an] I want to calculate the sum of the distance between every pair of the same element.

1)First element of array will always be zero.

2)Second element of array will be greater than zero.

3) No two consecutive elements can be same.

4) Size of array can be upto 10^5+1 and elements of array can be from 0 to 10^7

For example, if array is [0,2,5 ,0,5,7,0] then distance between first 0 and second 0 is 2*.  distance between first 0  and third 0 is 5* and distance between second 0 and third 0 is 2*. distance between first 5 and second 5 is 1*. Hence sum of distances between same element is 2* + 5* + 2* + 1* = 10;
For this I tried to build a formula:- for every element having occurence more than 1 (0 based indexing and first element is always zero)--> sum =  sum + (lastIndex - firstIndex - 1) * (NumberOfOccurence - 1) 
if occurence of element is odd subtract -1 from sum else leave as it is. But this approach is not working in every case.
,,But this approach works if array is [0,5,7,0] or if array is [0,2,5,0,5,7,0,1,2,3,0]
Can you suggest another efficient approach or formula?

Edit :- This problem is not a part of any coding contest, it's just a little part of a bigger problem

Comment: Seems like the easiest approach would be to have two nested `for` loops, and iterate through the array. It's O(n^2) time complexity, but is simple.

Comment: At first I thought of the same approach but this is time consuming that's why I tried to come up with a formula, but it didn't worked for every case

Comment: This problem uses a strange definition of "distance." It seems more simple to define the distance between the first two 0's in your example as `3` rather than as `2`, since the difference of the indices is `3 - 0 = 3`. Is your definition of "distance" necessary? Also, could you show an example where your approach does not work?

Comment: @DivyanshRajput's approach fails for [0,0,0,0,1,2,0]. Brute-force gives me 18, their method gives me 19.

Comment: Right @ThomasJager, this approach fails for some examples, that's why I asked for some another approach.

Comment: It was more directed at Rory who asked for an example that failed.

Comment: OH, I forget to add one more fact, first element of array is always 0 and second element can only be greater than 0. Rest of array contains elements greater than equal to 0. Also no two consecutive elements can be same.

Comment: @DivyanshRajput Your method *will not* work. You need to consider the distribution, not just the number and first and last indices. [0,1,0,2,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,10,0] has a result of 66 while [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0] is 54. Using your method, these two arrays give the same answer. **Distribution matters.**

Comment: @ThomasJager Thanks for pointing out that distribution matters. I couldn't think of it at first. So, is there any efficient approach that you can think of?

Comment: @DivyanshRajput Is there an upper limit on the values that can be present?

Comment: The number lies between 0 and 10^7

Comment: @DivyanshRajput Ok, that doesn't really help. If they were guaranteed small, you could keep track of various values to know exactly how much to add to your sum. I think this would has time complexity O(n*m) where m is the number of possible values. You could keep track of how much needs to be added for each element of a value you encounter. Every time you move forward by an element, you'd have to add the number of elements of that value encountered so far. For small m, it would effectively have O(n) time complexity.

Comment: @RoryDaulton You can think of distance as number of elements between two same elements

Comment: @ThomasJager  I am not able to get it clearly. Can you show by an example ? 
Also I want to make it clear that the size of array can be upto 10^5+1 and elements can lie between 0 to 10^7.

Comment: @ThomasJager well try this approach on [0,2,5,0,5,7,0,1,2,3,0]

Comment: My point is partly that an algorithm is easier with my definition of distance. I already have such an algorithm and will try to squeeze in the time to show it to you. I believe I can solve the problem with my definition then convert the answer to suffice for your definition. I'll test my ideas with Python code first. If I succeed and have the time I'll give you the algorithm and the Python code.

Comment: @DivyanshRajput I've updated my answer with something that has size complexity linear with number of possible values, but time complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method requires space that scales with the number of possible values for elements, but has O(n) time complexity.

I've made no effort to check that the sum doesn't overflow an `unsigned long`, I just assume that it won't. Same for checking that any input values are in fact no more than `max_val`. These are details that would have to be addressed.

For each possible value, it keeps track of how much would be added to the sum if one of that element is encountered in `total_distance`. In `instances_so_far`, it keeps track of how many instances of a value have already been seen. This is how much would be added to `total_distance` each step. To make this more efficient, the last index at which a value was encountered is tracked, such that `total_distance` need only be added to when that particular value is encountered, instead of having nested loops that add every value at every step.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// const size_t max_val = 15;
const size_t max_val = 10000000;

unsigned long instances_so_far[max_val + 1] = {0};
unsigned long total_distance[max_val + 1] = {0};
unsigned long last_index_encountered[max_val + 1];

// void print_array(unsigned long *array, size_t len) {
//   printf("{");
//   for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
//     printf("%lu,", array[i]);
//   }
//   printf("}\n");
// }

unsigned long get_sum(unsigned long *array, size_t len) {
    unsigned long sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      if (instances_so_far[array[i]] >= 1) {
        total_distance[array[i]] += (i - last_index_encountered[array[i]]) * instances_so_far[array[i]] - 1;
      }

      sum += total_distance[array[i]];

      instances_so_far[array[i]] += 1;
      last_index_encountered[array[i]] = i;

      // printf("inst ");
      // print_array(instances_so_far, max_val + 1);
      // printf("totd ");
      // print_array(total_distance, max_val + 1);
      // printf("encn ");
      // print_array(last_index_encountered, max_val + 1);
      // printf("sums %lu\n", sum);
      // printf("\n");
    }

    return sum;
}

unsigned long test[] = {0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0};

int main(void) {
  printf("%lu\n", get_sum(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0])));
  return 0;
}
```

I've tested it with a few of the examples here, and gotten the answers I expected.

I had to use static storage for the arrays because they overflowed the stack if put there.

I've left in the commented-out code I used for debugging, it's helpful to understand what's going on, if you reduce `max_val` to a smaller number.

Please let me know if you find a counter-example that fails.

Comment: unsigned long get_sum(unsigned long *array, size_t len) {
    unsigned long sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      if (total_distance[array[i]] >= 1)
        sum += total_distance[array[i]];
      /* This is the inefficient part */
      for (size_t j = 0; j <= max_val; ++j) {
        total_distance[j] += instances_so_far[j];
      }

      instances_so_far[array[i]] += 1;
    }
    return sum;
}


I checked the above approach, this approach does works fine for every possible case within the constraints, but it takes eternity to give the result.

Comment: Let me check the new approach that you have provided

Comment: Bingo! the latest code that you shared works perfect and it's time efficient.

Comment: Can you please enlight me with the thought process?

Comment: @DivyanshRajput I thought about what happens every time you encounter a number. If you've seen it before, you add the number of spaces between it and each of the previous ones seen. I started with a less efficient solution (the one there before you refreshed the page) which updated this number that needs to be added to the sum. From there, I thought about what I could do to get rid of having to act on every possible value every time.

Comment: @DivyanshRajput Also, using those print statements helped me visualise places where my algorithm failed be being able to see step-by-step what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your support, it's good to be a part of a community where everyone is willing to help each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Python 3 code for your problem. This works on all the examples given in your question and in the comments--I included the test code.

This works by looking at how each *consecutive* pair of repeated elements adds to the overall sum of distances. If the list has 6 elements, the pair distances are:

```
x  x  x  x  x  x  The repeated element's locations in the array
 --               First, consecutive pairs
    --
       --
          --
             --
 -----            Now, pairs that have one element inside
    -----
       -----
          -----
 --------        Now, pairs that have two elements inside
    --------
       --------
 -----------     Now, pairs that have three elements inside
    -----------
 --------------  Now, pairs that have four elements inside
```

If we look down between each consecutive pair, we see that it adds to the overall sum of all pairs:

```
 5  8  9  8  5
```

And if we look at the differences between those values we get

```
   3  1 -1 -3
```

Now if we use my preferred definition of "distance" for a pairs, namely the difference of their indices, we can use those multiplicities for *consecutive* pairs to calculate the overall sum of distances for *all* pairs. But since your definition is not mine, we calculate the sum for my definition then adjust it for your definition.

This code makes one pass through the original array to get the occurrences for each element value in the array, then another pass through those distinct element values. (I used the `pairwise` routine to avoid another pass through the array.) That makes my algorithm `O(n)` in time complexity, where `n` is the length of the array. This is much better than the naive `O(n^2)`. Since my code builds an array of the repeated elements, once per unique element value, this has space complexity of at worst `O(n)`.

```
import collections
import itertools


def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."""
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def sum_distances_of_pairs(alist):
    # Make a dictionary giving the indices for each element of the list.
    element_ndxs = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for ndx, element in enumerate(alist):
        element_ndxs[element].append(ndx)

    # Sum the distances of pairs for each element, using my def of distance
    sum_of_all_pair_distances = 0
    for element, ndx_list in element_ndxs.items():
        # Filter out elements not occurring more than once and count the rest
        if len(ndx_list) < 2:
            continue
        # Sum the distances of pairs for this element, using my def of distance
        sum_of_pair_distances = 0
        multiplicity = len(ndx_list) - 1
        delta_multiplicity = multiplicity - 2
        for ndx1, ndx2 in pairwise(ndx_list):
            # Update the contribution of this consecutive pair to the sum
            sum_of_pair_distances += multiplicity * (ndx2 - ndx1)
            # Prepare for the next consecutive pair
            multiplicity += delta_multiplicity
            delta_multiplicity -= 2
        # Adjust that sum of distances for the desired definition of distance
        cnt_all_pairs = len(ndx_list) * (len(ndx_list) - 1) // 2
        sum_of_pair_distances -= cnt_all_pairs
        # Add that sum for this element into the overall sum
        sum_of_all_pair_distances += sum_of_pair_distances

    return sum_of_all_pair_distances


assert sum_distances_of_pairs([0, 2, 5, 0, 5, 7, 0]) == 10
assert sum_distances_of_pairs([0, 5, 7, 0]) == 2
assert sum_distances_of_pairs([0, 2, 5, 0, 5, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]) == 34
assert sum_distances_of_pairs([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]) == 18
assert sum_distances_of_pairs([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 10, 0]) == 66
assert sum_distances_of_pairs([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0]) == 54
```